# I don't know how to get_chat_members_count with aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am writing a bot and I can't find a clear answer to how to get number of members in the group and when a user writes `/count` in the bot, he would get the number of participants in the group.

tell me pls what's wrong. Here is the code I made:

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

from config import token

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['count'])
async def getCountMembers(message: types.Message):
    await bot.get_chat_members_count(-1001519650013)


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aiogram has great documentation, you need to specify the chat_id

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

from config import token

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['count'])
async def getCountMembers(message: types.Message):
    # you can get the chat id like so
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    # otherwise instead of getting the chat id from the incoming msg just do 
    # chat_id = -1001519650013

    await bot.get_chat_members_count(chat_id=chat_id)


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

[aiogram documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x-api-5.7-with-features/api/methods/get_chat_members_count.html?highlight=get_chat_members_count)

Answer (score 1):

In ***aiogram*** version **3.x** you can use [**`get_chat_member_count`**](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/get_chat_member_count.html#module-aiogram.methods.get_chat_member_count) method like this:

```py
from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.filters import StateFilter
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.types import Message

from bot.states import States

some_router = Router()

@some_router.message(F.text, StateFilter(States.some_state))
async def some_message(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_id = "@somechat"
    count_of_members = await state.bot.get_chat_member_count(chat_id=chat_id)
    # ...
```

Answer (score -1):

The **get_chat_members_count()** method should pass the bot's chat id to the **chat_id** parameter

Comment: please provide more information to form a complete answer, your answer is not very helpful or clear

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).